# C# Closing a specific form in a multiform application

Tags: c#, winforms

I hope you can help me with this one. My application is monitoring a database for alerts. When  a alert shows up in the database, my application will add it to the main form in a datagridview, and depending on its priority it will also create a small winform popup with the event.

In the datagridview is a button to flag the alert as "seen", it will then update the database and be it will be gone from the list. However the popup form for this event is still open.

Does anyone know how to close this form? I need a way to find a specific form between the possible multiple alert forms that are open.

The closest I have come this far is the following code:

```
private void closeForm(int id)
{
    foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(id) == f.Name)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Which works up until the point that it closes the correct form. then it gives an error saying *"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."* This kinda makes sense, but I simply can't figure out another way to do it.

I have a winform class called `Alert`, wich makes the new forms. As you can see they will get a standard text "Alarm" and a unique Name based on the alert ID.

```
Alert alertform = new Alert(id);
alertform.Name = formid;
alertform.Text = "Alarm";
alertform.Show();
```

I hope someone has some good ideas how I can go about this. I have searched but cannot realy find a simple and elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add break; to your loop after you close the form. The collection is modified when you close the form (that form is removed from the collection), thus rendering the foreach loop invalid. And should you not be calling f.Close, rather than this.Close?

```
private void closeForm(int id)

    {
        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)

            if (Convert.ToString(id) == f.Name)
            {
                f.Close();
                break;

            }
    }
```

Comment: This looked like a very nice and simple sollution for my problem. But for some reason it shuts down my whole application with this.

Comment: @Mike Did you change the "this.Close();" to "f.Close();"?

Comment: @Mike Added that comment in an edit as I only noticed it after I posted the code sample, sorry. But glad you found your solution.

Comment: Well this will only work with one single Alert showing at the same time but it will work :D

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox As I understood it, he only wanted to close the Alert which was clicked as "seen", NOT all alerts.

Comment: It works like A Charm, even with 11 alert forms open it closes the correct one, and only that one. Wich is exactly what i need it to do.

Answer (score 4):

You should simply be able to store a reference to your form in the `DataGridView` or its `DataSource` then close the form using that reference. This approach is less likely to break in the future than iterating over all the application forms.

What would probably work best is to add a hidden column to the `DataGridView` that holds the form id, then also have a `Dictionary<int, Form>` which you use to get the reference to the Form you want to close.

Then you can simply get the form reference out of the dictionary and call close on it:

```
private void CloseAlertForm(int id)
{        
    Form f = dict[id];
    f.Close();
    dict.Remove(id);
}
```

Additionally you could store `Action` delegates instead of form references allowing you to slightly decouple the alert forms and the grid form.

Comment: Would you be able to type a little sample code for this? not so much to store a refernce to the datagridview, but how to use this to close the form.

Comment: All you guys (and maybe girls) i am amazed how many great answer i got and how fast.  I found one that is working for me, not saying the others ones aren't also good sollutions. But well i only need one :-)  and this one was the easiest for me to implement. Thanks all for your great responds! Mike

Answer (score 3):

just get ref. from `foreach` loop and close the `form` outside it.

```
private void closeForm(int id)
{   
        Form formtoclose=null;
        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(id) == f.Name)
            {
                formtoclose = f;
            }
        }
        if(formtoclose!=null)
        formtoclose.Close();
}
```

Comment: or in LINQ ;) `var f = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(form => form.Name == id).FirstOrDefault(); if (f != null) f.Close();`

Comment: your code will not compile btw, because `formtoclose` is unassigned. You'd have to set `formtoclose` to null before the loop (and obviously check whether it isn't still null before calling `Close` on it).

Comment: Yes i checked that, and it does not compile.

Comment: +1, this is the most direct fix for the two problems behind the question: Closing this and not the found form, and doing it in the ForEach.

Comment: @Konrad Application.Forms is a "primitive" List; it does not support Linq operators like 'Cast. This code will never compile.

Answer (score -1):

A Close modifies your OpenForms collection, so instead of enumeration over the OpenForms collection directly, you could enumerate over a copy.

LINQ is very handy into making copies, like this:

```
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms.Where(i => Convert.ToString(id) == i.Name).ToList()) {
      // Save to close the form here
}
```

The ToList executes the query, and stores the copy.

Comment: Application.Forms is a "primitive" List; it does not support Linq operators like 'Where. This code will never compile.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the type of the forms to find them (And `ToArray` to create a new collection an avoid changing the collection you are enumerating).

```
private void CloseAlerts()
{
    var openForms = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>();
    foreach (var f in openForms.Where(f => f is Alert).ToArray())
    {
        f.Close();
    }
}
```

In this case you don't need to set a name :

```
Alert alertform = new Alert(id);

alertform.Text = "Alarm";

alertform.Show();
```

Comment: All you guys (and maybe girls) i am amazed how many great answer i got and how fast.  I found one that is working for me, not saying the others ones aren't also good sollutions. But well i only need one :-)  and this one was the easiest for me to implement. Thanks all for your great responds! Mike

Comment: Application.Forms is a "primitive" List; it does not support Linq operators like 'Where. This code will never compile.

Answer (score -2):

```
var names = Application.OpenForms.Select(rs=>rs.name).ToList()

foreach (string name in names)
    if (Convert.ToString(id) == name)
    {
        Application.OpenForms[name].Close();
    }
```

Comment: Application.Forms is a "primitive" List; it does not support Linq operators like 'Select. This code will never compile.